# “The X you asked me to Y” (cantonese)

Tags: cantonese

I am not so familiar with how you say this in english grammar. But how do you say this pattern in cantonese?

For example: the bag you asked me to buy.

What is the syntax when translating to cantonese ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

“The (n) you asked me to (v)”

> 1. 你叫我(v)嗰個(n)

Example:

“The (bag) you asked me to (buy)” = "你叫我(買)嗰個(袋)"

“The (person) you asked me to (kill)” = "你叫我(殺)嗰個(人)"

> 2. 嗰個你叫我(v)嘅(n)

Example:

“The (bag) you asked me to (buy)” = "嗰個你叫我(買)嘅(袋)"

“The (person) you asked me to (kill)” = "嗰個你叫我(殺)嘅(人)"

> 個 is the classifier for the noun, replace 個 with other classifier when necessary

For example:

你叫我做嗰(件)(事)

嗰(件)你叫我做嘅(事)

The classifier for  '事' is '件', not '個'

> In many cases, you cannot transfer English grammar directly into Chinese  sentence, this is one of them "嗰個袋(that bag) 你叫我買 (you asked me to buy)" is not grammatical in Chinese